# Create a view in MSSQL where one column in a table depends on the value of another column in the same table

Tags: sql-server

How can I create a view in MSSQL where one column in a table depends on the value of another column in the same table?

Example:
I have 4 tables: placeType, schools, shops and hospitals and deliveries.

placeType has two columns(id and name) with three rows(school, shop and hospital)

schools has two columns(id and name) with a list of schools

shops has two columns(id and name) with a list of shops

hospitals has two columns(id and name) with a list of hospitals

deliveries has three columns(id, placeType and placeId) where the data is saved based on user selection.

The view should read from deliveries table, showing respective names for placetype and placename in each row.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum. Please have a look at this question: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing, however you might want to change your schema a bit.

By having three tables, your solution becomes greatly extensible.

Place, PlaceType, and Delivery

This way, each place has a type associated to it, and the delivery table only needs to reference the ID column of the Place table to do all the reporting you might need in the project's current state.
I've also added a couple foreign key constraints, just to help give a greater degree of referential integrity.

```
CREATE TABLE PlaceType
(
    PlaceTypeID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,Name       VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.PlaceType
(
    Name
)
SELECT ( 'School')
UNION ALL
SELECT ( 'Shop')
UNION ALL
SELECT ( 'Hospital');

CREATE TABLE dbo.Place
(
    PlaceID      INT         IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,Name        VARCHAR(100)
    ,PlaceTypeID INT         FOREIGN KEY (PlaceTypeID) REFERENCES dbo.PlaceType
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Place
(
    Name
    ,PlaceTypeID
)
SELECT 'Wildcat Elementary' , 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Main St Grocery' , 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Downtown Hospital' , 3;

CREATE TABLE Delivery
(
    DeliveryID    INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,PlaceID      INT FOREIGN KEY (PlaceID) REFERENCES dbo.Place
    ,DeliveryDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Delivery
(
    PlaceID
    ,DeliveryDate
)
SELECT 2 , '1/1/2020'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , '5/12/2020'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 , '7/12/2020';
```

Here is the code in a SQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/725fb/1

Here is the view which would give you the data you're asking for.

```
SELECT  d.DeliveryDate
        ,p.Name AS PlaceName
        ,pt.Name AS PlaceType
FROM    dbo.Delivery AS d
        INNER JOIN dbo.Place AS p ON p.PlaceID = d.PlaceID
        INNER JOIN dbo.PlaceType AS pt ON pt.PlaceTypeID = p.PlaceTypeID;
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. This represents exactly what I was looking for, if not better. Appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Joseph! Could you do me a favor and mark it as the answer please? :-)